# Layer package file generated in 2019 does not open anymore in arcmap 10.4.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scene-layer-package

I constructed a landform map in Arcmap for a region in Africa (made with a DEM) that cost me quite some time to make. When trying to open it, I get the pop-up box "could not open specified file". It does the same thing for some other layer package files that I made myself during that time. Other layer package files that contain rivers, streams, road for the areas still work, but they were made by someone else, before 2017. Also, layer package files that were made later in 2021 and contain point features still work.

What could be going on here? Could the files be corrupted? If so, how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 was released in 2016.  The 2019 layer package was probably created with a later version of ArcMap and can't be opened with the older software.  Update to newer ArcMap and you should be able to open the layer package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to opening an ".aprx" in ArcMap, you cannot roll back certain datasets as the schema does not match Esri's input schema.

My only guess is that someone created the working datasets within older software, and the ones that are not working in newer. You can export to an earlier version if you have access to ArcGIS Pro:

- Open your layer package in ArcGIS Pro.
- Right-click on the layer package in the Catalog pane.
- Choose "Sharing" > "Create Layer Package."
- In the Create Layer Package tool, there should be an option to select the version of the layer package. Choose the version that corresponds to your target ArcGIS version.

Otherwise, you may need to manually recreate the layer package or move to a newer version of ArcMap / ArcGIS Pro.